Estimate Hardy–Littlewood maximal function of a characteristic function
Given a cube $ Q $ in $ \mathbb{R}^d $ centered at $x_Q$ with side length $ l_Q $, let $\chi_Q $ be the characteristic function of $ Q$. The goal is to show that:
\begin{align}
\frac{l_Q}{|x - x_Q|} \lesssim \left[ \mathfrak{M}(\chi_Q)(x) \right]^{1/d},
 \hspace{0.2cm}x\notin Q.
\end{align}
where $ \mathfrak{M}(\chi_Q)$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of the characteristic function $\chi_Q$ of the cube $Q$.
My first thought is to use the idea of a problem in Loukas Grafakos book by the title of Classical Fourier Analysis, on page 86
example of computing the Hardy–Littlewood maximal function in $\mathbb{R}$, but I have difficulty in visualizing the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Thanks to everyone for your precious time.

Assuming the constant is allowed to depend on $d$, here would be my approach:
First, we can show that there is a constant $C_d$ such that $$Q\subseteq\overline{B_{C_d|x-x_Q|}(x)}.$$
(use triangle inequality, an upper bound for the distance between a point in $Q$ and $x_Q$, and a lower bound for the distance between a point in $Q^c$ and $x_Q$.)
From here, note that the average of $\chi_Q$ over $B_{C_d|x-x_Q|}(x)$ is a lower bound for the value of the maximal function at $x$. Then, using the fact that the integral of $\chi_Q$ over this region is exactly $m(Q)$, we get exactly the lower bound we're looking for.

Could you help me with the part involving the triangle inequality? I would greatly appreciate it.

If we suppose that $y\in Q$, to show that $y$ is in a closed ball centered at $x$, we must bound $|x-y|$. We know that $|y-x_Q|\leq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d}l_Q$ (half the length of the diagonal of the cube) and $|x-x_Q|\geq \frac{1}{2}l_Q$ (the distance between $x_Q$ and $\partial Q$). Putting these together, we have $|y-x_Q|\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d}l_Q\leq\sqrt{d}|x-x_Q|$. So, $$|x-y|\leq|x-x_Q|+|y-x_Q|\leq |x-x_Q|+\sqrt{d}|x-x_Q|=(1+\sqrt{d})|x-x_Q|.$$Letting $C_d=1+\sqrt{d}$, we have that $y$ is within a closed ball of radius $C_d|x-x_Q|$ centered at $x$.
